# hex codec / base64 encoding in PHP (converting from python)

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to convert some python code to PHP.  It looks so simple!

```py
def decode(self, cformat, params):
        if params[0:2] == 'gz':
            ps = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(params[4:]))
        else:
            ps = self.hex_decoder(params)[0]
        return struct.unpack(cformat, ps)
```

The structure itself is 6 4-byte numbers (floats mostly)  (https://gitlab.com/jochen.keil/dtlapse/-/blob/master/dtlapse/iops/exposure.json)

So for the zipped decompression in PHP, I'm trying

```php
        $gz = "gz01eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ==";
        $a = base64_decode(substr($gz, 4, strlen($gz)));

        $b = gzinflate($a);
        $vals = unpack('iffff', $b);
        dd($y, $x, $vals);
```

Nowhere close.  I'm missing something important in unpack, and maybe in the decompression as well.

Similarly, for the uncompressed string, which uses the hex decoder codec from python.  Not

```php
        $hex = "00000000000000001c5a044000004842000080c000000000";
        $data  = unpack('c*', $hex);
//        dd(pack('iffff', $data));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note `gzdeflate()` == compression. You probably want `gzinflate()`.

Comment: Thx, I've editted the question to reflect that.  Alas, it won't inflate that string.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at your situation, I tried comparing [the related Python code](https://gitlab.com/jochen.keil/dtlapse/-/blob/master/dtlapse/xcoder.py) result with the PHP side of things based on your PHP code given above. In a situation like this, I like to try to make sure each program has similar output throughout function related steps. That way you can see where the error might be happening (if any).

For reference, here is the modified Python code from the [`dtlapse`](https://gitlab.com/jochen.keil/dtlapse/-/blob/master/dtlapse/xcoder.py) project that I used to check things on the Python side:

```
# Copyright (C) 2020 Jochen Keil <jochen.keil@gmail.com> and contributors
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import binhex
import zlib
import base64
import codecs
import struct

class XCoder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hex_encoder = codecs.getencoder('hex_codec')
        self.hex_decoder = codecs.getdecoder('hex_codec')

    def decode(self, cformat, params):
        ps = None
        if params[0:2] == 'gz':
            print("gz params")
            print(params[4:])
            print("base64 decode")
            print(base64.b64decode("eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ==").hex())
            ps = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(params[4:]))
            print("zlib decompress")
            print(ps.hex())
        else:
            ps = self.hex_decoder(params)[0]
        return struct.unpack(cformat, ps)

    def encode(self, cformat, *cparams):
        return self.hex_encoder(struct.pack(cformat, *cparams))[0]

example = XCoder()
print(example.decode('iffffi', "gz01eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ=="))
```

**Python Code Output:**

```
gz params
eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ==
base64 decode
789c636080009928160706060f2706868603203e0016780285
zlib decompress
00000000000000001c5a044000004842000080c000000000
(0, 0.0, 2.067999839782715, 50.0, -4.0, 0)
```

Based on your PHP code and the related Python code from `dtlapse`, this is what I used (along with some deleted code) to check things on the PHP side:

```
<?php

$gz = "gz01eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ==";

echo "gz params\n";
echo substr($gz, 4, strlen($gz)), "\n";

echo "base64 decode\n";
$a = base64_decode(substr($gz, 4, strlen($gz)));
echo bin2hex($a), "\n";

echo "zlib decode\n";
$b = zlib_decode($a);
echo bin2hex($b), "\n";

// Note: with `unpack()` on PHP, I think you need to specify the individual
// items differently than like the Python side with `struct.unpack()` as
// used in the dtlapse code:
// https://gitlab.com/jochen.keil/dtlapse/-/blob/master/dtlapse/xcoder.py
// With PHP, it is putting the results into an associative array, so it
// needs to know how to title the associate array keys.
$vals = unpack('iitem0/fitem1/fitem2/fitem3/fitem4/iitem5', $b);
print_r($vals);

// Expected output from Python side looks like this:
// (0, 0.0, 2.067999839782715, 50.0, -4.0, 0)
$final_results = array_values($vals);
print_r($final_results);

// I think PHP might have some sort of built-in reason for why it shows float
// values that are like 0.0 or 50.0 as 0 and 50, even though they are floats.
// You can double-check that these are floats on the PHP side using this:
var_dump($final_results);

?>
```

**PHP Code Output:**

```
gz params
eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ==
base64 decode
789c636080009928160706060f2706868603203e0016780285
zlib decode
00000000000000001c5a044000004842000080c000000000
Array
(
    [item0] => 0
    [item1] => 0
    [item2] => 2.0679998397827
    [item3] => 50
    [item4] => -4
    [item5] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2.0679998397827
    [3] => 50
    [4] => -4
    [5] => 0
)
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  float(0)
  [2]=>
  float(2.0679998397827)
  [3]=>
  float(50)
  [4]=>
  float(-4)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
}
```

From the gz params, base64 decode, and zlib related lines, things looked alright (if I'm remembering correctly) between the different code versions. I also used [this online app](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex) to verify the base64 decode part because I was getting something strange from the Python side until I added [`.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) at the end of this line: `print(base64.b64decode("eJxjYIAAmSgWBwYGDycGhoYDID4AFngChQ==").hex())`.

So, it seems like the issue on the PHP side from your earlier code especially relates to this part:

```
$b = gzinflate($a);
$vals = unpack('iffff', $b);
dd($y, $x, $vals);
```

Instead of using `gzinflate()`, I ended up using [`zlib_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-decode) because this seemed to be similar to the Python [`zlib.decompress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html?highlight=zlib#zlib.decompress) approach.

For the [`unpack()` function in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php), that function in PHP appears to put the found values into an associative array and the associative array keys are set depending on what you put next to the item's type. So for example, if you need to get three values (an int and two floats, for example) you might use the following `$format` parameter: `iint\ffloat1\ffloat2` which, if everything goes well with the `unpack()` function, should end up with a result array like:

```
// ref: Based on examples from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php
Array
(
    [int] => 1
    [float1] => 2.0
    [float2] => 3.0
)
```

In your case, the format that I used was like this:

```
$vals = unpack('iitem0/fitem1/fitem2/fitem3/fitem4/iitem5', $b);
```

This ends up with an array like this with the given code from earlier in this answer:

```
Array
(
    [item0] => 0
    [item1] => 0
    [item2] => 2.0679998397827
    [item3] => 50
    [item4] => -4
    [item5] => 0
)
```

But in case you want a simplified array, you can also use the following line (with [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)):

```
$final_results = array_values($vals);
```

To get a closer result to the Python version from the `dtlapse` project, which was this:

```
(0, 0.0, 2.067999839782715, 50.0, -4.0, 0)
```

And here is the simplified PHP array result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2.0679998397827
    [3] => 50
    [4] => -4
    [5] => 0
)
```

Even though PHP appears to make float values look like integers (when the float value is something like `50.0` where there is only a `0` directly after the decimal point), you can verify that the value types are still floats by using the `var_dump()` function like in the PHP code example earlier in this answer.

This is the PHP output showing that the middle values really are floats:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  float(0)
  [2]=>
  float(2.0679998397827)
  [3]=>
  float(50)
  [4]=>
  float(-4)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Anyway, I hope this helps!